# Rails nested form, attributes not getting passed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, nested-attributes

So I have a `Conversation` model, which `has_many` `messages`. I'm trying to create a new message when I create a conversation. Here's my `ConversationsController`:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def new
    recipient = User.find(params[:user])
    @conversation = Conversation.new(from: current_user, to: recipient)
    @conversation.messages.build(from: current_user, to: recipient)
  end

  def create
    @conversation = Conversation.create(params[:conversation])
    redirect_to @conversation
  end
end
```

And here's my form (`conversations/new.html.erb`):

```
<%= form_for @conversation do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :messages do |g| %>
    <%= g.label :subject %>
    <%= g.text_field :subject %>
    <%= g.label :content %>
    <%= g.text_field :content %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

The problem: when I submit the form, the conversation's message gets saved, but the `to` and `from` fields that I specified as parameters in `build` are not saved (they are nil). However, the `subject` and `content` fields filled out in this form are saved just fine.

I've done a little bit of digging... if I do a `puts` on `@conversation.messages` in the `new` action, or in the `new.html.erb`, the message seems to have `to` and `from`. It's only when the message reaches the `create` action do those fields disappear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED:

```
class ConversationsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  def new
    recipient = User.find(params[:user])
    @conversation = Conversation.new(to: recipient)
    @conversation.messages.build
  end

  def create
    @conversation = current_user.conversations.build(params[:conversation])

    # Set all the attributes for conversation and messages which
    # should not be left up to the user.
    @conversation.to = current_user
    @conversation.messages.each do |message|
      message.to = @conversation.to
      message.from = @conversation.from
    end

    redirect_to @conversation
  end
end

<%= form_for @conversation do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :recipient %>
  <%= f.fields_for :messages do |g| %>
    <%= g.label :subject %>
    <%= g.text_field :subject %>
    <%= g.label :content %>
    <%= g.text_field :content %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit "Send" %>
<% end %>
```

You may still want to validate the recipient in your Conversation model.

Comment: Well I could consider removing `from` and `to` from Conversation, which I think would make more sense... Consider that in a given conversation, I could send a message to you, and you could send a message to me, reversing the `to` and `from` each time...

Comment: 2 things: Is there no way to do this except for hidden fields? Also, how would I validate the recipient?

Comment: You need some way of keeping track of the recipient across requests.  You could do it as URL parameter (maybe as a nested resource) instead of using a hidden field.  Validation is up to you, and it will depend on  your application.  Should a user be able to submit any recipient ID, or should the recipient be one of the two members of the conversation?  Some ActiveRecord validations should help check whatever conditions you need.